# What version of Rake Pipeline (rakep) am I using

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, asset-pipeline

I'm using Ruby's Rake Pipeline to build an Ember.JS app and would like to know which version it is so I can research some problems I am having. Here is the command used to execute my build

```
bundle exec rakep build
```

I was hoping for something like

```
bundle exec rakep -version
```

but can't find a reference to anything like this.

Comment: Just a friendly tip - use the Ember-cli instead. The rails build tools are are developmental dead end and Ember-cli is the official way to go.

Comment: Thanks @max. We are moving to Ember-CLI, but we'll need to use the Rake in the meantime.